# How to get Size of the application

Tags: java, android, filesize

I am trying to get the application size

and i tried [PackageStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageStats.html)

```
        mPackageStats = new PackageStats(package_name);

        app_apk_size = mPackageStats.codeSize;

        app_cache_size = mPackageStats.cacheSize;

        app_data_size = mPackageStats.dataSize;
```

But getting 0

What's wrong with the code or any other method?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no public api to retrieve size information about application packages. But you can check [`this blog`](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/android-package-size) how we can get the size of the Application using reflection.

Comment: thanks for info `IPackageStatsObserver` cannot be resolved to a type.where can i find this class? pls elaborate.

Comment: This method works greatly. Thanks again for help. but as he said that `While this works it is obviously a big hack to work around a missing piece of Android API. Reaching past the SDK is never a good idea, especially for public applications.` . So should i consider this method or there is any other clean way to do this?

Comment: There is no other clean way, but for now you can manage by this one.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to my own blog post two years later - THX! :)